JSpinner - Dynamic Max and Min Value at RunTime
I need to be able to change the Max and Min value of a JSpinner set-up with SpinnerDateModel and DateEditor when they change dynamically at Runtime.
The initialization code to set-up the JSpinners is as below:
jSpinner_StartDateTime = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
jSpinner_EndDateTime = new javax.swing.JSpinner();

jSpinner_StartDateTime.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel(new java.util.Date(), null, null, java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
jSpinner_StartDateTime.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
 public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
  jSpinner_StartDateTimeStateChanged(evt);
 }
});

jSpinner_EndDateTime.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel(new java.util.Date(), null, null, java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
jSpinner_EndDateTime.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
 public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
  jSpinner_EndDateTimeStateChanged(evt);
 }
});
jSpinner_StartDateTime.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(jSpinner_StartDateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS"));
jSpinner_EndDateTime.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(jSpinner_EndDateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS"));

I have two Date variables that change through the program at runtime and I need to be able to set the Max, Min and Value of the JSpinner dynamically at Runtime based on these variables.
Date StartDateTime, EndDateTime;

When I use the below code, the UI is not getting updated.
jSpinner_StartDateTime.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel(StartDateTime, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, java.util.Calendar.SECOND));
jSpinner_EndDateTime.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel(EndDateTime, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, java.util.Calendar.SECOND));

                

However, if I use the below code, the correct value from the Date variables gets displayed on respective JSpinners, but the values are not restricted to the range.
jSpinner_StartDateTime.getModel().setValue(StartDateTime);
jSpinner_EndDateTime.getModel().setValue(EndDateTime);

I am not able to figure out what the issue is and/or what I am doing wrong and/or how to achieve what I need.
Any help / advise appreciated, please.
Update:
Adding a working example to demonstrate my issue:
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;

public class SpinnerIssueExample extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton_Update;
    private javax.swing.JSpinner jSpinner_EndDateTime;
    private javax.swing.JSpinner jSpinner_StartDateTime;
    
    private Date StartDateTime, EndDateTime;
    private boolean flag = false;

    public SpinnerIssueExample() {
        initComponents();
        {
            jSpinner_StartDateTime.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(jSpinner_StartDateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS"));
            jSpinner_EndDateTime.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(jSpinner_EndDateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS"));
        }
        updateDates();
    }

    private void updateDates() {
        do {
            StartDateTime = new Date((2020 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (2025 - 2020))), 
                (1 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (12 - 1))), 
                (1 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (27 - 1))), 
                (0 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (23))), 
                (0 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (59))), 
                (0 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (59))));
            
            EndDateTime = new Date((2020 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (2025 - 2020))), 
                (1 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (12 - 1))), 
                (1 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (27 - 1))), 
                (0 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (23))), 
                (0 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (59))), 
                (0 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (59))));
        } while (StartDateTime.after(EndDateTime));

        {
            System.out.println("StartDateTime -> " + StartDateTime);
            System.out.println("EndDateTime -> " + EndDateTime);
        }

        //  Alternatively use different methods I used that did not fulfill my requirements.
        //  This will demonstrate my issue.
        if (flag) {
            jSpinner_StartDateTime.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel(StartDateTime, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, java.util.Calendar.SECOND));
            jSpinner_EndDateTime.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel(EndDateTime, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, java.util.Calendar.SECOND));
            flag = false;
        } else {
            jSpinner_StartDateTime.getModel().setValue(StartDateTime);
            jSpinner_EndDateTime.getModel().setValue(EndDateTime);
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jSpinner_StartDateTime = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
        jSpinner_EndDateTime = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
        jButton_Update = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jSpinner_StartDateTime.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel(new java.util.Date(), null, null, java.util.Calendar.SECOND));
        jSpinner_EndDateTime.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel(new java.util.Date(), null, null, java.util.Calendar.SECOND));

        jButton_Update.setText("Update Dates");
        jButton_Update.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton_UpdateActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jSpinner_StartDateTime, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 533, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jSpinner_EndDateTime)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton_Update)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jSpinner_StartDateTime, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jSpinner_EndDateTime, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton_Update)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        pack();
    }

    private void jButton_UpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { updateDates(); }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SpinnerIssueExample.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SpinnerIssueExample.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SpinnerIssueExample.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SpinnerIssueExample.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SpinnerIssueExample().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

If you run it and click on the button to load random dates, the dates in the Spinners will update alternatively.
Example Output below:
As you can see in the first image, the values update.
In the second one they don't.
It repeats every time you click the button to Update dates.
When it update in the UI, it will not limit the dates to the Start and End Dates.



Maybe try updating the editor after resetting the model? Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Added code example.

There are "setter" methods for start, end and calendar field - as well as for value - in class SpinnerDateModel, refer to the documentation. If you say that calling setValue works, then I think you should try the other "setters" and see if that resolves your problem.

JSpinner and related classes use the poorly designed Date class that has been outdated for over 10 years. There are alternatives out there suing the modern LocalDate class instead. Were it me, I would no doubt take one of those.

@Abra, That helped, I created global SpinnerDateModel variables and updated the models instead of the Spinner and now it is working perfectly.

The below code worked for me.
Thanks @Abra.
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;

public class SpinnerDatesExample extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private javax.swing.JButton jButton_Update;
    private javax.swing.JSpinner jSpinner_EndDateTime;
    private javax.swing.JSpinner jSpinner_StartDateTime;

    private SpinnerDateModel StartDateModel, EndDateModel;

    private Date StartDateTime, EndDateTime;
    //private boolean flag = false;

    public SpinnerDatesExample() {
        initComponents();
        {
            jSpinner_StartDateTime.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(jSpinner_StartDateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS"));
            jSpinner_EndDateTime.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(jSpinner_EndDateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS"));
        }
        {
            StartDateModel = (SpinnerDateModel) jSpinner_StartDateTime.getModel();
            EndDateModel = (SpinnerDateModel) jSpinner_EndDateTime.getModel();
        }
        updateDates();
    }

    private void updateDates() {
        do {
            StartDateTime = new Date((2020 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (2025 - 2020))),
                    (1 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (12 - 1))),
                    (1 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (27 - 1))),
                    (0 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (23))),
                    (0 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (59))),
                    (0 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (59))));

            EndDateTime = new Date((2020 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (2025 - 2020))),
                    (1 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (12 - 1))),
                    (1 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (27 - 1))),
                    (0 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (23))),
                    (0 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (59))),
                    (0 + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (59))));
        } while (StartDateTime.after(EndDateTime));

        {
            System.out.println("StartDateTime -> " + StartDateTime);
            System.out.println("EndDateTime -> " + EndDateTime);
        }

        //  Alternatively use different methods I used that did not fulfill my requirements.
        //  This will demonstrate my issue.
        /*if (flag) {
            jSpinner_StartDateTime.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel(StartDateTime, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, java.util.Calendar.SECOND));
            jSpinner_EndDateTime.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel(EndDateTime, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, java.util.Calendar.SECOND));
            flag = false;
        } else {
            jSpinner_StartDateTime.getModel().setValue(StartDateTime);
            jSpinner_EndDateTime.getModel().setValue(EndDateTime);
            flag = true;
        }*/
        {
            StartDateModel.setStart(StartDateTime);
            StartDateModel.setEnd(EndDateTime);
            StartDateModel.setValue(StartDateTime);
        }
        {
            EndDateModel.setStart(StartDateTime);
            EndDateModel.setEnd(EndDateTime);
            EndDateModel.setValue(EndDateTime);
        }
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jSpinner_StartDateTime = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
        jSpinner_EndDateTime = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
        jButton_Update = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jSpinner_StartDateTime.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel(new java.util.Date(), null, null, java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        jSpinner_EndDateTime.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel(new java.util.Date(), null, null, java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));

        jButton_Update.setText("Update Dates");
        jButton_Update.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton_UpdateActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(jSpinner_StartDateTime, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 533, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(jSpinner_EndDateTime)
                                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                .addComponent(jButton_Update)))
                                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addComponent(jSpinner_StartDateTime, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jSpinner_EndDateTime, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton_Update)
                                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        pack();
    }

    private void jButton_UpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        updateDates();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SpinnerDatesExample.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SpinnerIssueExample().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

